More efficient way to perform np.hstack
I detected that the np.hstack operation over a list of arrays is a bottleneck in my pipeline and I would like to have a more efficient way to perform the concatenation.
Here a sample code to get to the input that I have for the hstack step:
matrix = np.zeros([5,4])
list_arrays=np.hsplit(matrix, matrix.shape[1])
#----- perform some (parallel) operation on columns
matrix = np.hstack(list_arrays) #--> I would like to optimize this

any idea?

hstack uses concatenate, the core function for making a new array from multiple arrays.  Each those arrays in the list have to be copied to the target.  That sets a limit on speed.

yeah, I was thinking also about something like a Cython solution, do you think it is feasible?

It would be very helpful to know what your "parallel operation" actually is. In general, I don't see a need why you would want to split and merge your array around your calculations. One of the beauties of working with Numpy is that, if you use it to your advantage, it usually doesn't need such constructs (and no explicit for loops either). So giving more detail on your concrete problem would help providing you with a concrete solution. I would suggest you provide a minimal, reproducible example (needn't be your actual code).

Basically, for efficiency, I need to split columns to apply a normalization function that I parallelize to columns with ThreadPoolExecutor, whose output is a list that I need to hstack. With this technique, I managed to halve execution time (w.r.t. plain numpy)

As already commented, without knowing what exactly you do in the parallelized part of your code, it is hard to provide a tailored solution. That said, in the following code, I assume you want to calculate the softmax over each column, and I provide 5 different implementations:

calculate_with_split(): Uses a ThreadPoolExecutor on each column, like you mentioned in your comments to the question, and splitting the array beforehand. I assume this is the closest to what you are actually doing.
calculate_with_pool(): Uses a ThreadPoolExecutor on each column, but doesn't split the input.
calculate_with_loop(): Uses a loop over the columns, processing them one after the other.
calculate_vectorized(): Uses Numpy's vectorization capabilities.
calculate_in_place(): Uses Numpy's vectorization capabilities and calculates the result in-place, i.e. alters the given array.

from concurrent.futures import ALL_COMPLETED, ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, as_completed
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np

num_workers = 16
num_timings = 1000
shape_matrix = 500, 40

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers)

def normalize(data: np.ndarray, axis: int | None = None):
    # Compute a numerically stable softmax for normalization
    numerator = np.exp(data - data.max(axis=axis, keepdims=True))
    return numerator / numerator.sum(axis=axis, keepdims=True)

def calculate_with_split(matrix):
    list_arrays = np.hsplit(matrix, matrix.shape[1])
    fs = [pool.submit(normalize, col) for col in list_arrays]
    wait(fs, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
    return np.hstack([f.result() for f in fs])

def calculate_with_pool(matrix):
    result = np.empty_like(matrix)
    idx_by_future = {pool.submit(normalize, col): idx for idx, col in enumerate(matrix.T)}
    for f in as_completed(idx_by_future):
        result[:, idx_by_future[f]] = f.result()
    return result

def calculate_with_loop(matrix):
    result = np.empty_like(matrix)
    for i in range(matrix.shape[-1]):
        result[:, i] = normalize(matrix[:, i])
    return result

def calculate_vectorized(matrix):
    return normalize(matrix, axis=0)

def calculate_in_place(matrix):
    np.subtract(matrix, matrix.max(axis=0, keepdims=True), out=matrix)
    np.exp(matrix, out=matrix)
    np.divide(matrix, matrix.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True), out=matrix)

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
matrix = rand.normal(size=shape_matrix)

result_split = calculate_with_split(matrix)
result_pool = calculate_with_pool(matrix)
result_loop = calculate_with_loop(matrix)
result_vect = calculate_vectorized(matrix)

matrix_copy = matrix.copy()
calculate_in_place(matrix_copy)
result_in_place = matrix_copy

assert np.allclose(result_split, result_pool)
assert np.allclose(result_split, result_loop)
assert np.allclose(result_split, result_vect)
assert np.allclose(result_split, result_in_place)

for fct in calculate_with_split, calculate_with_pool, calculate_with_loop, calculate_vectorized, calculate_in_place:
    print(f"{fct.__name__}(): {Timer(lambda: fct(matrix)).timeit(num_timings):.3f} seconds")

As a result, I get:
calculate_with_split(): 2.532 seconds
calculate_with_pool(): 1.983 seconds
calculate_with_loop(): 0.622 seconds
calculate_vectorized(): 0.203 seconds
calculate_in_place(): 0.194 seconds

The conclusion I draw from this: In case your problem is remotely similar in dimensionality and complexity to the code shared above and in case you manage to rewrite your problem, pretty much any solution will be faster than using the split-and-merge approach.
I may misjudge your problem though, as it is still not clear to me what you are actually doing. In any case, maybe the code above can help you with experimenting and optimizing the solution to your actual problem.

They said "the np.hstack operation over a list of arrays is a bottleneck'. Is that the case in your code? How much time does np.hstack take here?

@nocomment As to your first question: I don't know. As to your second question: I don't know. Then again: Do you know the situation with OP's setup other than their claim you are citing?

No, I don't, which is why I upvoted your MRE request and wouldn't do anything until they provide one. But I tried yours and np.hstack seems to take only about 4% of the runtime, really not a bottleneck, so your code doesn't seem to reflect theirs at all. (Though I do suspect they're wrong about np.hstack being a bottleneck, and measuring that would be the first thing I'd do with their MRE.)

@nocomment Fair enough. I wrapped the calculation with a cProfile.Profile and agree with your 4% finding for hstack. I also agree that OP might misjudge their situation. I just drew a different conclusion. Rather than waiting for a MRE, I provided my own. Indeed I might be trying to solve the wrong problem here, but I don't see what is wrong with leaving that up to OP's judgment.

Hmm, I'd say an "MRE" that doesn't reproduce the stated issue isn't an MRE...

@nocomment Again, agreed. But this brings me back to: I don't see what is wrong with leaving that up to OP's judgment.
